# How to cache some requests based on request rate?

Tags: nginx, cache, varnish, cdn

We have some super heavy APIs, say `/api/heavy`, it will slow down our system when peak time, we did some benchmark, if the simultaneous request count is greater than 200, the system becomes slow, and if greater than 600, our system becomes unavailable.

We are unable to add `redis` or `memcached` layer right now, because it needs to update the source code which is not possible right now for some contract problem.

So we are thinking to put some cache server in front of our API server, and cache these APIs for 10 seconds when the request rate > 500 and 3 seconds when the rate > 150.

How can we do this using `Nginx` or `Varnish`? Or other solutions? CDN?

Comment: Pretty sure you can do this with CloudFlare, but you'd need one of the higher subscription plans. It sounds like something that should be possible with Nginx as well.

Comment: Does this API returns the same answer for all clients?

Comment: @AlexeyTen no, it differs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by [nuster cache server](https://github.com/jiangwenyuan/nuster)

```
# cache /heavy for 100 seconds if be_conn greater than 10
acl heavypage path /heavy
acl tooFast be_conn ge 100
nuster rule heavy ttl 100 if heavypage tooFast
```

I don't know if the API is private or shared? In case it's private, meaning the result of the API differs per user, you can also cache `/api/heavy` per user like this:

```
nuster rule heavy key method.scheme.host.uri.cookie_sessionID ttl 100 if heavypage tooFast
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Possible approach using Varnish: during `vcl_recv` use [Redis VMOD](https://github.com/carlosabalde/libvmod-redis) (disclaimer: I'm the author) or some throttling VMOD (e.g. `vsthrottle` included in https://github.com/varnish/varnish-modules) to check / update request rate to the API end-point. If not over the limit skip the cache simply doing a `pass`. Otherwise do a `hash` and cache as preferred during `vcl_backend_response`. This can be easily generalized if more than one limit is needed.

`vsthrottle` is way simpler than the Redis approach, but obviously is local to each Varnish instance. Usually that's ok for a throttling scenario, so no need to add Redis to your stack in most cases.